# Sharepoint 2010, Create Content based website

Tags: sharepoint, web, content-management-system

I did not use sharepoint before!!

Did you use Share-point 2010 before?, MS is saying that it can do a CMS website and without previous sharepoint version limitations, I am worry about that:-

1- 
Can I create whatever I need in UI layer? 
Any designer does not let me do things at the lowest level, (HTML, JQUERY, Javascript, CSS), will cause great troubles, does that apply on share-point?

2- 
Is it really compatible with FF, and Chrome browsers, or I will find my self in deep troubles.

3-
Do u know anything that makes me not creating a CMS site like this http://www.editeur.org/ using sharepoint 2010 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These websites use SharePoint:

- http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/
- http://www.cadbury.co.uk/
- http://www.ferrari.com/

As you can see, **it is possible to create highly customized layouts**. However, you need to be aware that **the learning curve is steep** - you have never used SharePoint before, so there's a lot of learning ahead of you.

---

SharePoint 2010 supports non-IE browsers better than SharePoint 2007. [This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx) contains a detailed analysis of this problem. There seems to be no known limitations related to content management, but you'll have to test it yourself to be sure.

Comment: There is definitely a steep learning curve. If you want to user sharepoint as a cms then you really should pick up a few books because you need to learn about the taxonomy and content structure system that are the building blocks of sharepoint.